# Does one MySQL Query Freeze All Other Upcoming Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I want to perform a MySQL query once every hour to count some rows from one table (over 10M rows) and update an int value in a different table. The query takes about 1-2 minutes to complete. While processing this query, would I be able to run other MySQL SELECT queries?

Comment: In principle yes.  Databases can support multiple queries at the same time.  Of course, the available resources depend on your hardware and system parameters.  Try testing running multiple queries at the same time to see what happens.

Comment: Only count? Why dont you increment a counter at "insert"s instead? Using simple locking mechanism would keep counting thread-safe. But if you have multiple machines, then I dont know.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Its for an app where I must keep all distinct values and their count. It's complicated lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, database structures are intended for near simultaneous access of data. The speed of each query is dependent on server resources allocated to each, so you may experience slower query time than expected.